# Different FourierParameters in each dimension for discrete Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a query about the Fourier utility, that does discrete Fourier transforms. I am unable to find any information on whether different `FourierParameters` can be used in each dimension. This is a natural thing to do in wave theory where you have $\exp(i (k x-\omega t))$ representations. Is it possible for example to use `FourierParameters -> {1, 1}` for the first dimension and `{1, -1}` for subsequent dimensions?

Background information (if useful):

Specifically, I use `FourierParameters -> {1, 1}` for the time dimension and `{1, -1}` for two spatial dimensions. I wish to take a Fourier transform of a large (960 × 256 × 256) array where the dimensions are $(t,x,y)$. This works, but is slow.

```
Ftxy[h_] := Module[{Hxy}, Hxy = Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] & /@ h;
  Transpose[Map[Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}] &,
    Transpose[Hxy, {3, 2, 1}], {2}], {3, 2, 1}]]
```

This also works, but is slower

```
Ftxy3[h_] := With[{n = Length[h]}, N[Exp[-2 π I Range[0, n - 1]/n]]*
   Fourier[Reverse[h], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]
```

The raw 3D `Fourier[]` is fast, but multiplying through by the complex exponential vector is the slowest part. I tried setting `FourierParameters ->
 {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}`, but that is not accepted.

Comment: Maybe `f[h_] := RotateRight@Reverse@Fourier[h, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`

Comment: Thanks Simon. That's very elegant, and fixes my immediate problem. However, the general issue remains of whether different, more general FourierParameters can be used in each dimension rather than applying  some sort of post-processing.

Comment: Now, here's a question whose answers I'll be very interested in…